# AOS Animation Not Firing Correctly After Browser Resize

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

AOS is working great when this page first loads. Each "white square" animation fires at the same time and all 6 squares are visible. I am noticing, though, that when I resize the browser to a smaller size and then size it back up to be larger again, the AOS in combination with the media query I set is causing some of the blocks to go missing. This isn't consistent, but if you keep resizing you will find a point where you will only see 2 blocks out of 6, or 4 blocks out of 6. Please Try for yourself, I have isolated the code here:

http://www.blacksanddesign.com/stack-overflow-question-1.html

And here is an image so you can see what I'm referring to:

[image]

Anyone know what may be causing this? Help is much appreciated. Thank you!

```js
<script src="aos.js"></script>

 <script>
   AOS.init({
    easing: 'ease-in-out-sine'
   });
  </script>
```

```css
body{
 margin:0;
}
.block#features {
 background-color:black;
 padding-top:100px;
 padding-bottom:100px;
 text-align:center;
}

.title#features{
 font-size:30px;
 color:white;
 padding-bottom:75px;
}

.features{
 width:87%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 font-size:0;
 text-align:center;
}

ul{
 padding-left:0;
 padding-right:0;
 font-size:0;
}

li{
 list-style-type:none;
 background-color:white;
 width: 32.73%;
 display:inline-block;
 padding-top:30px;
 text-align:center;
 margin:.3%;
 vertical-align:top;
 height: 250px;
 padding-left:0;
 padding-right:0;
}

.features h2{
 font-size:20px;
}

.features p{
 font-size:12px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 li{width:100%}
}
```

```html
<link href="http://www.blacksanddesign.com/css/aos.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="block" id="features">
<div class="title" id="features">OFFERING YOU</div>
<div class="features">
<ul>
<li aos="zoom-in"><h2>hello</h2><p>hello</p></li>
<li aos="zoom-in"><h2>hello</h2><p>hello</p></li>
<li aos="zoom-in"><h2>hello</h2><p>hello</p></li>
<li aos="zoom-in"><h2>hello</h2><p>hello</p></li>
<li aos="zoom-in"><h2>hello</h2><p>hello</p></li>
<li aos="zoom-in"><h2>hello</h2><p>hello</p></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your second link is not working

Comment: Thanks, working on it...

Comment: The link to the image has been fixed...

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue
and used

```
let samt = 0;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
samt <= 10 ? samt++ : AOS.refresh();
});
```

My Problem is solve

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Next.js and figured out the problem. Mainly, when you initialize **AOS**, it looks for scroll for that exact **height** and width. So, when the resize or any other content changes the position of the elements using **AOS**, it messes up.

The animation works, but not as we intend it to. If I have 3 div each with `height:100px`:

- `div1`
- `div2` *(has **AOS** fade animation)*
- `div3`

If I change the height of `div1` to `200px`, animation of `div2` will run when my screen's bottom reaches `200px`. But when the animation fired up, I was still on `div1` as it's height is now `200px`.

So, the solution is:

Call `AOS.refresh()` whenever the `window.innerWidth` or `window.innerHeight` changes.

Answer (score 0):

it will not work if the element your scrolling from not the body!!
for example :
you have an

inside your HTML and it's the one you're scrolling from it won't work! only the body

Comment: it looks something is missing in your answer.

Comment: I mean if you're scrolling from another element rather than the body it won't work !!!  for example, if you have <main> element inside the <body> and want to scroll from it IT WON'T WORK!!!